# The table I put is too big, how can I make it smaller?

Tags: tcolorbox

I'm putting a table inside a tcolorbox and the table gets out of the tcolorbox and the pdf, is there any tool with which I could make the table smaller? (Like making the font smaller).

Here's what I wrote:

```
\ejemplo{En la tabla adjunta

\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        Edad (años) & Frecuencia & Frecuencia porcentual & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Frecuencia porcentual\\ acumulada\end{tabular} \\ \hline
        14          & 4          & $16\%$                & $16\%$                                                                    \\ \hline
        15          & 7          & $28\%$                & $44\%$                                                                    \\ \hline
        16          & 6          & $24\%$                & $68\%$                                                                    \\ \hline
        17          & 8          & $32\%$                & $100\%$                                                                   \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
El percentil 73 corresponde al valor bajo el cual se encuentra el $73\%$ de los datos, y la menor frecuencia porcentual acumulada que iguala o sobrepasa dicho porcentaje es $100\%$. Luego, el percentil 73 es 17 años.
}
```

And here's the result:
[image: Result]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: put all your headings on two lines, as you did in the last column

Comment: How or where is `\ejemplo` defined? Which document class do you employ? How wide is the text block? Equivalently, which paper size you you employ, and how wide are the horizontal margins? Which main document font size is in use?